# Toggle text in clicking link

Tags: javascript, html, css, hyperlink, toggle

I have the below code that toggles a `<div>` (called `#casamarron`) into view:

```js
$('.expandir').on('click', function(e) {

  $(this).text(function(i, s) {
      return s === 'mostrar' ? 'ocultar' : 'mostrar';
    });

});
```

my click link is this:

```html
<div id="casamarron">

<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="expandir" style="background: none;border: none;color: #5a3696;font-size: 11.5px;float: left;">mostrar</a>
```

So it doesn't work, shows the "mostrar" word but doesn't change

How do I get that 'Expand' text to change to read 'Collapse' when the `#casamarron` div is visible?

Comment: Please make a (minimal) workable prototype so we can see the issue more clearly.

Comment: I try it works fine for me, i used this version of jQuery: https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js

Comment: man, I'm using the same version of jQuery, but when I try it on live html page, it doesn't, I'm getting crazy, do me a favour, if it works for you, give me your functional code